# Date Picker Selected Cell CSS

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Ok, so I've changed the DatePicker style with a bit of CSS modification; however, the selected date no longer shows. Here is my new DatePicker

[image]

and here is my css to make this snazzy thing possible

```
.date-picker-popup > .month-year-pane {
    -fx-padding: 0.588883em 0.5em 0.666667em 0.5em;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-main-back;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0;
}

.date-cell {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-main-back;
    -fx-font-family: "Andalus";
    -fx-font-size: 16.0;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-type;
}

.date-cell:hover {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-type;
    -fx-font-family: "Andalus";
    -fx-font-size: 16.0;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-main-back;
}
```

Not sure what the css is for the selected date. I've tried all kinds of stuff like

```
.date-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-type;
    -fx-font-family: "Andalus";
    -fx-font-size: 16.0;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-main-back;
}

.date-cell:focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-type;
    -fx-font-family: "Andalus";
    -fx-font-size: 16.0;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-main-back;
}

.date-cell-selected {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-type;
    -fx-font-family: "Andalus";
    -fx-font-size: 16.0;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-main-back;
}
```

If someone could help me out with this one I'd appreciate it. In review I need to change the color of the date that is selected when you open the thing up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The date cell for the selected date gets a style class (not a pseudoclass) of `selected`, so

```css
.date-cell.selected {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-type;
    -fx-font-family: "Andalus";
    -fx-font-size: 16.0;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-main-back;
}
```

will work.